# Move background sprite infinitely from left to right ? How can I achieve such an effect?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a sprite that has to be scrolled from the left side of the screen to the right. The width of the sprite is greater than the dimensions of the iPhone. I want to create a loop along the x-axis, the y- value of the sprite stays the same.

Comment: Do you want the sprite to completely disappear off the right side of the screen before appearing again on the left?

Comment: No, I want it to be a nice transitional kind of effect... So that the part, that is off the right side immediately appears on the left side.

Comment: There's a contradiction. If your sprite is wider than the screen, how can the part that passes off the right side immediately appear on the left? There's more sprite left.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NSTimer` to trigger the following method.

```
(void)moveSprite {
   CGRect f = sprite.frame;
   if (f.origin.x == [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width) {  // end of the screen
      f.origin.x == 0-sprite.size.width;
   }
   else {
      f.origin.x += kPixelsPerFrame;
   }
   sprite.frame = f;
}
```